# Presentation of a non-abelian group of order $p^4$ such that ${G}/{\Phi(G)}\cong \Bbb{Z}_p\times \Bbb{Z}_p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^4$ 
and $\frac{G}{\Phi(G)}\cong \Bbb{Z}_p\times \Bbb{Z}_p$, 
where $p$ is a prime. What is the presentation(s) of $G$?(If $G$ exixsts).

Thanks for any answer or comment!

Comment: Perhaps such group doesn't exist...

Comment: @  Alexander Konovalov For example by GAP we can check that there exist 7 non-abelian groups of orders 81 and 625 with this property.

Comment: You're right. Yesterday I did not put a list around the last argument of `AllSmallGroups` in  `p:=3;l:=AllSmallGroups(Size,p^4,g->IdGroup(g/FrattiniSubgroup(g)),[IdGroup(ElementaryAbelianGroup(p^2))]);` but it's documented behaviour says that if the _value_ is a list, then it considered a list of possible function values to include. Therefore seeing `[ 9, 2 ]` it was looking for values $9$ and $2$ instead of the group Id - not surprisingly I've got an empty list :)

Answer (score 1):

One such example is $$\langle a,b,c,d \mid a^p=b^p=1,[a,b]=c,[a,c]=[b,c]=d, [a,d]=[b,d]=1 \rangle,$$ which works for any prime $p$, but there are other groups with this property.

*Added later*: For some reason I looked for an example with nilpotency class $3$, but there are examples with class $2$, such as $$\langle a,b,c \mid a^{p^2}=b^p=c^p=1, [a,b]=c, [a,c]=[b,c]=1 \rangle.$$

Comment: Dear professor Holt, Is it posible to explain your method to obtain this presentation? Many thanks!

Comment: Not very easily.I was just trying to write down a presentation of a group of order $p^4$ with class $3$ that worked for all primes $p$, and that is what I eventually came up with (I first tried $[b,c]=1$, but that doesn't work for $p=2$.) But I have realized that there are examples with class $2$ that are probably easier to understand.